# How do I search the Chrome Web Store for apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chrome-web-store

Ok, Chrome apps still exist, u just cant search for them because you will get extensions results… BUT, here is an example of one App

[Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookies/iphcomljdfghbkdcfndaijbokpgddeno)

if u search “cookies” this app wont show up…

very simple question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is phasing out the use of Chrome Apps. They've likely removed them from the storefront to prevent new users from beginning to rely on apps that will be completely unsupported later this year. To learn more about this, you can [read this Chromium Blog post about it](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/moving-forward-from-chrome-apps.html).

Comment: Not much anyone can do about it now. It's not an impossibility that someone could make a new chrome extension that could take over the job of an old app.